discord bot についてです。
import asyncio
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

# コンソールの使用に関するノイズを抑制
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'  # ipv6アドレスで問題が発生する場合があるため、ipv4にバインド
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # プレイリストから最初のアイテムを取得
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)

class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.queue = []

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        """ボイスチャンネルに参加"""
        if ctx.author.voice:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            if ctx.voice_client is not None:
                return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)
            await channel.connect()
            await ctx.send(f'{channel} に接続しました。')
        else:
            await ctx.send("ボイスチャンネルに接続されていません。")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
        """ローカルファイルを再生"""
        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        self.queue.append(source)
        if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            self.play_next(ctx)
        await ctx.send(f'再生キューに追加: {query}')

    @commands.command()
    async def yt(self, ctx, *, url):
        """URLから再生 (ほぼ全てのyoutube_dlがサポートするもの)"""
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            self.queue.append(player)
            if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
                self.play_next(ctx)
        await ctx.send(f'キューに追加しました: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def stream(self, ctx, *, url):
        """URLからストリーミング (ytと同じですが、事前にダウンロードしない)"""
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            self.queue.append(player)
            if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
                self.play_next(ctx)
        await ctx.send(f'キューに追加しました: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def volume(self, ctx, volume: int):
        """プレイヤーの音量を変更"""
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("ボイスチャンネルに接続されていません。")
        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = volume / 100
        await ctx.send(f"音量を{volume}%に変更しました")

    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        """停止してボイスチャンネルから切断"""
        self.queue.clear()
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("再生を停止し、ボイスチャンネルから切断しました。")

    @commands.command()
    async def list(self, ctx):
        """使用可能なコマンドを表示"""
        commands = (
            "!join - ボイスチャンネルに参加",
            "!play <ファイルパス> - ローカルファイルを再生",
            "!yt <URL> - YouTubeなどから再生",
            "!stream <URL> - YouTubeなどからストリーム再生",
            "!volume <音量（0-100）> - 音量を変更",
            "!stop - 再生を停止して切断"
        )
        await ctx.send("使用可能なコマンド:\n" + "\n".join(commands))

    def play_next(self, ctx):
        if self.queue:
            next_player = self.queue.pop(0)
            ctx.voice_client.play(next_player, after=lambda e: self.play_next(ctx) if e is None else print(f'プレイヤーエラー: {e}'))
        else:
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(ctx.voice_client.disconnect(), self.bot.loop)

    @play.before_invoke
    @yt.before_invoke
    @stream.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("ボイスチャンネルに接続されていません。")
                raise commands.CommandError("ボイスチャンネルに接続されていないユーザーです。")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

# 必要なすべてのIntentsを有効にする
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.voice_states = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"),
                   description='シンプルな音楽ボットの例',
                   intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'ログインしました {bot.user} ({bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

# ここでCogを追加する
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
bot.run('TOKUN')

asyncio.run(main())

このコードを実行すると
year-month-date h:m: INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
year-month-date h:m: INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: ??????????????????????).
ログインしました 動画bot#???? (???????????)
------
year-month-date h:m:s ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found
year-month-date h:m: ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "list" is not found

となってしまいます。どうしたらよいですか？

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

16日に解決した旨を上記他サイトのほうに投稿いただいているようで、解決してよかったですね。こちらのサイトにもどのように解決したのか、メッセージ投稿をしていただけると幸いです。たしかアカウントを作成してすぐは自分の投稿に回答できないと思うので、投稿済みのメッセージを編集するか、ここのコメントに掲載できるはずです。
